# One Edge Piece Faced The Wrong Way

Tags: rubiks-cube

What is the minimum number of turns needed to solve a rubik's cube with one edge piece faced the wrong way on the 3rd layer?

Example

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> Not possible.
> For one cubelet to be off like that indicates that the cube was misassembled. See [here](https://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/unsolvable-rubiks-cube-invalid-scramble/) - any legal rotation or combination of rotations that involves flipped edge cubes will result in an even number of flipped edge cubes.

Comment: There is also http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/521/why-cant-i-have-only-one-edge-piece-flipped-on-a-3x3-rubiks-cube that asks essentially the same question, and the same principle applies to http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20/why-is-a-single-corner-twist-not-a-valid-position-on-a-rubiks-cube, which should be considered an answer to both this question and the edge question I linked to.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil - why spoilerize this? The situation is impossible, and not making that clear immediately does not seem reasonable.

Comment: I was going along the lines that someone who sees this might want to try this on their own, and that some people might want to see the answer

Comment: "Ah yes let me just try flipping an edge piece on my own for two hours..."

Comment: @greenturtle3141 I've met some weird people when it comes to rubiks cubes...